# Duel Plugin, sending requests and opening inventories with HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap, bukkit

I asked a similar question to this today, but I need help with further development.

The HashMaps:

```
Map<UUID, UUID> duels = new HashMap<UUID, UUID>();
Map<UUID, UUID> selecting = new HashMap<UUID, UUID>();
```

The command:

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("duel")) {
        if (!(args.length == 1)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " Usage: /duel <Player>");
            return true;

        } else if (args.length == 1) {
            Player p = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
            if (p != null) {
                if (p.equals(sender)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " You cannot duel yourself!");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    if (duels.containsKey(p) || duels.containsKey(sender)) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "] " + ChatColor.RED + "Either you or " + ChatColor.BLUE + p.getName() + ChatColor.RED + " are already in a duel!");
                        return true;
                    } else

                        openKitSelector((Player) sender);
                        selecting.put(p.getUniqueId(), ((Player) sender).getUniqueId());
```

The KitSelector inventory:

```
public void openKitSelector(Player p) {
    Inventory selector = Bukkit.createInventory(p, 9, ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "KitSelector" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]");

    ItemStack diamond = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD);
    ItemMeta diamondMeta = diamond.getItemMeta();
    diamondMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "Diamond Kit");
    diamond.setItemMeta(diamondMeta);

    ItemStack iron = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_SWORD);
    ItemMeta ironMeta = iron.getItemMeta();
    ironMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "Iron Kit");
    iron.setItemMeta(ironMeta);

    selector.setItem(0, diamond);
    selector.setItem(1, iron);

    p.openInventory(selector);

}
```

The Accept/Deny inventory:

```
private void openGUI(Player player) {
    Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "DuelRequest" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]");

    ItemStack accept = new ItemStack(Material.EMERALD_BLOCK);
    ItemMeta acceptMeta = accept.getItemMeta();

    ItemStack decline = new ItemStack(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK);
    ItemMeta declineMeta = decline.getItemMeta();

    acceptMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "Accept!");
    accept.setItemMeta(acceptMeta);

    declineMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Decline!");
    decline.setItemMeta(declineMeta);

    inv.setItem(3, accept);
    inv.setItem(5, decline);

    player.openInventory(inv);
}
```

So what I need to happen is, when someone types `/duel <player>` , they will get an inventory up with a selection of items that will give them kits, which I have done correctly and tested. Then when they select a kit, the target of the `/duel` command will get an inventory with an accept item and decline item.

I got everything working up to the part were the target gets the inventory for accept or deny as I am not really experienced with HashMaps, and I am a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to get the target of a duel request from the `selecting` HashMap, you could use:

```java
UUID id = selecting.get(player.getUniqueId());
Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(id);
```

So, if you wanted to open the kit selector for the target, you could use:

```java
//get the UUID of the Player that is being targeted by the Player player
UUID id = selecting.get(player.getUniqueId());

//get the target Player from the UUID above
Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(id);

//open the kit selector for the target Player above
openKitSelector(target);
```

To open the target's inventory after the duel requester has selected their kit, you would have to listen for `InventoryCloseEvent`:

```java
@EventHandler
public void inventoryClose(InventoryCloseEvent e){
  //called when a player closes their inventory
}
```

So, your code could look like this:

```java
@EventHandler
public void inventoryClose(InventoryCloseEvent e){
  //check if the inventory is the duel inventory
  if(e.getInventory().getName().equals(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "DuelRequest" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]"){
    //get the player who opened the inventory
    Player p = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();

    //now, check if the selecting HashMap contains the Player above
    if(selecting.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())){
      //get the target of the duel
      Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(selecting.get(p.getUniqueId()));

      //open the kit selector for the target Player above
      openKitSelector(target);

      //now, remove the target's, and the sender's UUID from the selecting
      //HashMap, to make sure that we don't accidentally open the kit
      //selector for a player who is currently in a duel.
      selecting.remove(p.getUniqueId());

      //make sure the selecting HashMap contains the target's UUID before
      //attempting to remove it
      if(selecting.containsKey(target.getUniqueId())){
        selecting.remove(target.getUniqueId());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you wanted to make sure that the player clicks something in the inventory, you could use `InventoryClickEvent`:

```java
@EventHandler
public void inventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent e){
  //called when a player clicks something in a inventory
}
```

Also, you will have to switch around the order in which items are in the `HashMap`. Instead of using the target as the key, use the sender as the key:

```java
selecting.put(((Player) sender).getUniqueId(), p.getUniqueId());
```

So, your `onCommand` could look like this:

```java
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("duel")){
    if(!(args.length == 1)){
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " Usage: /duel <Player>");
        return true;
    }
    else if (args.length == 1){
        Player p = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
        if(p != null){
            if(p.equals(sender)){
               sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " You cannot duel yourself!");
                return true;
            }
            else{
                if(duels.containsKey(p) || duels.containsKey(sender)){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "] " + ChatColor.RED + "Either you or " + ChatColor.BLUE + p.getName() + ChatColor.RED + " are already in a duel!");
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    openKitSelector((Player) sender);

                    //this line was changed from
                    //selecting.put(p.getUniqueId(), ((Player) sender).getUniqueId())
                    //to the new value, with the sender as the key,
                    //and the target as the value.
                    selecting.put(((Player) sender).getUniqueId(), p.getUniqueId()); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have misunderstood what i mean, that may have been my fault for not explaining.
What i want to happen, when someone types /duel, they will get the kitSelector. Once they choose the kit they want, the target will then receive the accept/deny inventory. So the KitSelector is what is called before the accept or deny, then once a kit is chosen, the accept/deny is called.

Comment: So it kinda works, but i think there is an error when putting the players into the HashMaps, When i do /duel <Player> i get the Kit Selector up, then when i chose the kit, nothing happens. However, once i do /duel <player> from the other account, it works..

Comment: @MattyFenny Actually, take a look at my updated answer. Try using `selecting.put(((Player) sender).getUniqueId(), p.getUniqueId())` instead of `selecting.put(p.getUniqueId(), ((Player) sender).getUniqueId())` in your `onCommand()`

Comment: one problem, since its listening for an inventory close, when when i don't chose a kit, and just close the inventory, its still sending the duel request.

Comment: onInventoryClose is not needed anymore, works fine without it if i put the players into `duels` from the kitselector.

Comment: @MattyFenny Yes, you could use InventoryClickEvent to make sure they actually click something.